Why my nginx.conf cause http version error?
I'm using nginx to configure a forward proxy, but when I tested it, I got this error:
upstream sent no valid HTTP/1.0 header while reading response header from upstream, client: 11.176.19.31, s    erver: , request: "POST / HTTP/1.1"
I have added the configuration mentioned in the https://www.f5.com/company/blog/nginx/avoiding-top-10-nginx-configuration-mistakes#no-keepalives in nginx.conf.
My nginx.conf is as follows.
worker_processes  1;
error_log logs/error.log;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    server {
        listen 8080;
        
        location / {
            set $target_url '';
            access_by_lua_block {
                local cjson = require "cjson"

                ngx.req.read_body()
                local data = ngx.req.get_body_data()

                local ok, json = pcall(cjson.decode, data)
                if not ok then
                    ngx.status = ngx.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
                    ngx.say("Invalid JSON")
                    return
                end

                local url = json.url
                if not url then
                    ngx.status = ngx.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
                    ngx.say("Missing 'url' field")
                    return
                end

                ngx.var.target_url = url
            }
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   "Connection" "";
            resolver 10.123.119.98 10.123.120.110 10.85.61.21;
            proxy_pass $target_url;
        }
    }
}


The upstream will return a file to nginx.
